# Outdoor backup: gocryptfs --init --reverse: alway same .diriv in 1st level directory

Tags: encryption, ssh, file-system, backup

#### Intro

Trying to send encrypted backup of in productions filesystems, I was interested by the ability of using [gocryptfs](https://github.com/rfjakob/gocryptfs) in *reverse* mode!

The idea is to

- use `gocryptfs --reverse` from any existing (unencrypted) *folder*, for mounting an encrypted version of my *folder*.
- then backup the encrypted *folder* using `rsync`, `tar` or any usefull tool (`tar` 1st time, then `rsync` periodically).
- On remote backup server, I could use `cp -al` for duplicate (*hardlink*) backup *folder* to a *time stamped folder* (**note**: as fs is encrypted on remote, *time stamped folder* have to be created at source and his encrypted name must be passed to the backup server in any way for this become possible... I'm not alread totally clear about how I will do this. The method in my draft is working, but I'm not satisfied...)
- Further `rsync` will modify remote *folder* but won't change any  *time stamped folder*,
- Finally using `sshfs` to mount remote backup (in read-only) to my local machine, then
- I could use `gocrypts` (in *regular* way) from the mounted sshfs to *unencrypt*  backuped *folder* (and his copies).

( Full draft script here: [gocrypt-script.sh](https://f-hauri.ch/vrac/gocrypt-script.sh.txt) )

#### My doubt

Doing some test around *`gocryptfs`*, I noticed that the `gocryptfs.diriv` file is alway the same in 1st directory level when initialised in *reverse* mode:

```
$ gocryptfs -q -init -reverse test1 <<<'what a fucking strong pass phrase'
$ gocryptfs -q -init -reverse test2 <<<"another long'n strong pass phrase"
$ gocryptfs -q -init -reverse test3 <<<"shortPassword"
$ gocryptfs -q -reverse test1 <<<'what a fucking strong pass phrase' crypt1
$ gocryptfs -q -reverse test2 <<<"another long'n strong pass phrase" crypt2
$ gocryptfs -q -reverse test3 <<<"shortPassword" crypt3
$ sha1sum crypt?/gocryptfs.diriv
2c9b6702d05d2de71816666387f6d4ea3c28c9cd crypt1/gocryptfs.diriv
2c9b6702d05d2de71816666387f6d4ea3c28c9cd crypt2/gocryptfs.diriv
2c9b6702d05d2de71816666387f6d4ea3c28c9cd crypt3/gocryptfs.diriv
```

But this files differ when initalized in *normal* way:

```
$ mkdir test{4,5,6}
$ gocryptfs -q -init test4 <<<'what a fucking strong pass phrase'
$ gocryptfs -q -init test5 <<<'what a fucking strong pass phrase'
$ gocryptfs -q -init test6 <<<'what a fucking strong pass phrase'
$ sha1sum test?/gocryptfs.diriv
f38755738a0be70b6b103f6fdbdb05aaebb3ffe5 test4/gocryptfs.diriv
e2e64788a6e2f0a4554bc56d9b17e55471766398 test5/gocryptfs.diriv
206d278a405d3f826da842abdcdd37e475f9e02e test6/gocryptfs.diriv
```

After doing some more tests;
[gocrypt-test.sh](https://f-hauri.ch/vrac/gocrypt-test.sh.txt)

I could ensure each *master key* is clearly different! But I'm not sure about the meaning and implicaton of *`gocryptfs.diriv`* file... I wonder if this could significantly reduce required work for breaking the master key!?

#### Author answer

So I asked this [as an issue at git source server](https://github.com/rfjakob/gocryptfs/issues/786), author told me:

> Hi, yes, you are correct, the first level gocryptfs.diriv is always the same.
>
> As seen in https://nuetzlich.net/gocryptfs/reverse_mode_crypto/#derived-ivs , it's computed as
>
> ```
> sha256(path + \0 + DIRIV)
> ```

> This is not a problem. The only important thing thing about gocryptfs.diriv (Dir IV = Directory Initialisation Vector) is that you use different values for different directories within one file system.

Not totally convinced by this, I would appreciate more elaborated explanation.